# iOS: delete a specific object from a NSSet

Tags: ios, core-data, nsset

I have this code to store a NSSet in my entity "struct"

```
NSString *current_language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

        if (![current_language isEqualToString:@"en"] && ![current_language isEqualToString:@"fr"])
            current_language = @"en";

        NSMutableSet *deslocalization = [struct mutableSetValueForKey:@"localizedDes"];

        LocalizedDes *localizedDes = (LocalizedDes *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LocalizedDes" inManagedObjectContext:temporaryContext];
        localizedDes.locale = current_language;
        localizedDescrizione.desloc= [element objectForKey:@"des"];
        [deslocalization addObject:localizedDes];
```

as you can see I create a new Entity LocalizedDes and I add it to the NSSet desLocalization.
I can add two type of object inside this NSSet: a localizedDes with locale = "en" or "fr".

The I want one information, What's the way to delete inside this NSSet a specific object? At example only the object that has locale = "en".

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to implement isEqual and hash method in your LocalizedDes.

Then you can do:

```
[deslocalization removeObject:enLocale];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (LocalizedDes *localizedDes in [deslocalization copy]) {
    if ([localizedDes.locale isEqualToString@"en"]) {
        [deslocalization removeObject: localizedDes];
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, but why you use '[deslocalization copy]' and not 'deslocalization'

Comment: To not modify the set while iterating through it.

Comment: but I work in a temporanyContext, I think that there are not problems